# Why am I still getting a password prompt with ssh with public key authentication in grunt scp

Tags: ssh, gruntjs, scp

I am trying to deploy using `grunt-scp` and using RSA key for authentication but it's still asking for a password.
I have followed the following document for troubleshooting, but it seems that everything is fine if I try to `scp` from the shell itself, but it is not working for `grunt`.

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Troubleshooting

I am trying the following command from the workspace of my project:

```
grunt deploy --env=test
```

and I am getting following prompt:

```
Running "scp:deploy" (scp) task
[?] password:
```

All the permissions are in place and it is reading the key when I run the command in verbose mode.
And even if I put in the password manually, it gives me the following error:

```
[?] password: 
ssh connect test-server.niwa.co.nz
>> error Authentication failure. Available authentication methods: publickey,keyboard-interactive
ssh close test-server.niwa.co.nz
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. It seems the problem cames with the scp grunt plugin version 0.1.8. I did a downgrade to 0.1.7 and it worked.

Hope you can fix it.

Greets!

Comment: Could you paste here the configuration of the grunt scp task? Maybe could be helpul to find the solution ;)

Comment: scp: {
             deploy:{
               options: {
                  host: grunt.option('host') || settings.host,
               username: grunt.option('username') || settings.username,
         privateKey: fs.readFileSync(grunt.option('privateKey') || settings.privateKey),
         showProgress: true
         tryKeyboard: true
      }, 
      files: [
        { cwd: './dist', src: '', filter: 'isFile', dest: grunt.option('path')|| settings.path }

      ]  
    }   
  }

Comment: i try to change the key authentication to password authentication by putting `trykeyboard: true` but get this error   `Disconnected by host (PROTOCOL_ERROR): Too many authentication failures for user`